# Go up one directory in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a standard Zend Framework 1 project that looks a bit like this:

```
Project
|- public
 |- .htaccess
 |- index.php
```

The .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^image/.*$ img.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now I want to start transitioning the site to Zend Framework 2, which I put in a separate directory in the root, so the whole thing looks like this:

```
Project
|- public
 |- .htaccess
 |- index.php
|- zf2
 |- public
  |- .htaccess
  |- index.php
```

What would I have to change in my original (ZF1) .htaccess to route all requests to (for example) `/zf2/whatever` to ZF2's index.php? I've tried `RewriteRule ^zf2(/.*)$ ../zf2/public/index.php [NC,L]` in the line after `RewriteBase /`, but that just gives me a *400 Bad Request*.

Answer (score 2):

You need mod_alias, not mod_rewrite:

```
Alias /zf2/ ../zf2/public
```

Maybe you'll need to specify absolute path instead of relative.

Another solution would be use of a filesystem symbolic link named `zf2`, placed in `Project/public` and pointing to `../zf2/public`.

In both cases you'll need `Options +FollowSymlinks`. And be careful about  restrictions and where they apply to.

See [Accessing files outside the document root with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570085/accessing-files-outside-the-document-root-with-apache) on StackOverflow.